# How can i execute a program if the monster id doesnt exist?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current code.

```
    $monster_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xx_monsters WHERE MonsterId = '$monster_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$char_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xx_characters WHERE id = '" . $char_id . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$char = mysql_fetch_assoc($char_result);

if (mysql_num_rows($monster_result) > 0) {
    $monster_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xx_monsters WHERE MonsterId = " . $monster_id) or die(mysql_error());
   //I tried adding this, but for some reason it messed up the entire thing
   //exec("/usr/local/bin/lostID $monster_id");
} else {
    $level = $char['level'] + 1;
    $level2 = $char['level'] - 10;
    $monster_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xx_monsters WHERE Level < " . $level . " AND Level > " . $level2 . " AND ExtraData != 'trainer' AND ExtraData != 'starter' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
}
$monster = mysql_fetch_assoc($monster_result);
```

I tried to add it under else too, but it renders the page totally blank, there are echo statements after this. Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you mean if a particular ID does not exist in the database? Or if the user does not give a ID? (Anyway, it wasn't clear to me why you repeat the query twice, once as a string on line 1, once as a number on line 4: it might help if you show the DB schema.

Comment: echo the query in both conditions and directly run to mysql

Comment: The particualr id. Im not sure what the `> 0` line does, i coded that when following some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function `isset($variable_name)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

if(!empty($monster_id)) {

// your code here

}

Empty function will also make sure that variable value should not be null or empty string.